# Adding int and string into mySQL from Windows Form

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, winforms

Okay so i am trying to connect to my university db server and allow users of my program to submit a highscore which will then be stored in the db. The problem i am having is that the data IS NOT being added to the DB, but recieve no kind of error or message to say it hasnt.

this is the code for the button

```
private void btnSubmitScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "server=server; " +
                     "database=databse; " +
                     "uid=username; " +
                     "pwd=password;";

    string query = "INSERT INTO highscore('Name','Score')    VALUES (@Name, @Score);";
    using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(query);
        MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",sName);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score",iTotalScore);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception: " + ex);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

my variables are sName and iTotalScore which are to be added into two fields called 'Name' and 'Score' in the databse. I have looked online but dont seem to be able to find a solution.

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: What's the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()`? It will gives you the amount of rows affected by your statement, which should hopefully be 1. Double check that.

Comment: sorry arran but i dont have a clue how to do that :/

Comment: var result = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: On a side note, you do not need connection.close(), you already have it in a using(){}

Comment: Change `insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` to `int rowsAffected = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`...then check the value of `rowsAffected` after running that line. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is this expression connection.Open() working correctly?

Comment: @MikeC. I'd say that you should still close the connection even while in a using block. I think it's a better practice.

Comment: @Arran i changed what you said, but dont know how to check the value of rowsAffected.

Comment: @nsconnector how do i check if it is working? i dont get an error to say it isn't where as earlier today i was getting errors that it could not connect to mySQL.

Comment: @CainNeal try debugging step by step to see if that expression is executing without throwing exception

Comment: @CainNeal, use a breakpoint or even a simple `Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected)`...this may be a goose chase though!

Comment: @Arran rowsAffected = 0

Comment: @nsconnector when i run the connection open nothing happens at all, used a break point to run it.

Comment: I think you don't need a quote sign in column names try in your query string: INSERT INTO (Name, Score) VALUES...

Comment: Fabio is quite possibly right.  Square brackets maybe, but I don't think you can use string literals....

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your INSERT statement. You cannot put column names in any quote. Your statement should be:

string query = "INSERT INTO highscore (Name, Score) VALUES (@Name, @Score);";